# How to send personalised emails with dynamic attachements to a mailing list?

Tags: email, sendgrid, email-attachments

I have a mailing list on SendGrid that needs to be sent information from a database. This list is quite large and it would take days to manually transfer all the data and make 5000 separate PDF's from our excel spreadsheet.

Additionally, each email sent would need to have the specific PDF for that specific person in the mailing list. Each PDF would contain different information depending on the person's details.

How do I go about personalising each email from a generic template (e.g. Hi ____ etc.) and send dynamic attachments to each of the people on the mailing list that corresponds to their data?

I have tried to import data from excel into PDF's but am having trouble with this.

I have a relatively simple knowledge of coding and am not sure how I would go about making the email personalised and be able to send a dynamic attachment for each recipient.

Comment: I just had a quick google and would [something like this](https://pdfmailmerger.com/) help you do the job?

Comment: Thanks,

This would help with the Mail Merge from Excel to PDF. Still having trouble sending each of these personalised PDF's to different recipients based on a mailing list in SendGrid.

Comment: I think that service can send the emails for you too. I'm not sure you can send different attachments to everyone in a mailing list, so if you were going to do this with SendGrid you'd need to write a script that ran through a list and sent an email to each person with their personal PDF.